# In what way can I know the tables in a .db file using Python SQLite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

here's the code:

```
import sqlite3
cx = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cu = cx.cursor()

# create table 1.
cu.execute("create table user_info1 (user_id text primary key,followers integer, asks integer, answers integer, goods integer)")

# create table 2
cu.execute("create table user_info2 (user_id text primary key,followers integer, asks integer, answers integer, goods integer)")
```

Now I'm wondering to see how many tables are in test.db:

```
cu.execute('.tables') # doesn't work.

cu.execute('select * from test.sqlite_master where type = "table"')
# OperationalError: no such table: test.sqlite_master
```

The methods above doesn't work for me. Have any hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your database is not `test` (that would be part of the *file* name) but `main`:

```
cu.execute("SELECT * FROM main.sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'")
```

And `main` is the default database name, so you do not even need to specifiy it:

```
cu.execute("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'")
```

Comment: ^^; Thanks, quite clear.